# Run Cordova app using Chrome Device Mode Mobile Emulation

Tags: cordova, emulation, ripple

I have always used `ripple` to run my cordova app in desktop browsers.
But I know that there is a better tool to emulate mobile apps and it's integrated in chrome: `Chrome Device Mode Mobile Emulation`.

Is there a way to use `Chrome Device Mode Mobile Emulation` instead of using `ripple` to emulate my app in chrome?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Chrome remote debugging is easy and useful to monitor or debug network related bug in mobile application. Just follow the following steps.

Before that you have to add these lines in your application's src file (.java)

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    if (0 != (getApplicationInfo().flags &= ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE))
    { WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true); }
  }
```

(This will allow chrome to monitor running webview)

1. Enable USB debugging in your mobile
2. Connect your device with PC.
3. Open chrome in your PC
4. Go to Chrome menu > More tools > Inspect Devices.
5. Check in Discover USB devices check box
6. Find Your application in list
7. You can screencast your app to chrome now.

That is it!! You can debug your application from chrome.

**Note:-** Its only for android

Comment: ok thanks, I knew that method, I just wanted to know how to debug in desktop browser before deploy to phone. That's what `ripple` does and that's what I would like to replace using `Chrome Device Mode Mobile Emulation`

Comment: You can not get it that easy like `ripple` but from chrome just like inspecting web page, you can inspect mobile application. So you have to do debugging from code level by adding a lot of `console.log` unlike `ripple`

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to use Chrome Device Emulation with my Cordova app, however in the 'emulation' tab, under 'device' I had to uncheck 'emulate mobile' for the app to render like it would on a mobile device.